# Split page into many numbered Divs and reload whole page when clicking to show the hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="content_1">    
//Content of first page goes
</div>
<div class="content_2" style="display:none;">
//Content of second page goes here
</div>
<div class="content_3" style="display:none;">
//Third page content goes here
</div>

<p>Pages: 
<a href="#" class="button_1"> 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button_2"> 2</a>
<a href="#" class="button_3"> 3</a></p>
<div class="clearLeft"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var a = 200;
$('.button_1').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
$('.button_1').click(function(){
    $('.content_1').fadeIn(a);
    $('.content_2').fadeOut();
    $('.content_3').fadeOut();
        $('.content_4').fadeOut();
    $('.button_1').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
    $('.button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
$('.button_2').click(function(){
    $('.content_1').fadeOut();
    $('.content_2').fadeIn(a);
    $('.content_3').fadeOut();
        $('.content_4').fadeOut();
    $('.button_2').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
    $('.button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
$('.button_3').click(function(){
    $('.content_1').fadeOut();
    $('.content_2').fadeOut();
    $('.content_3').fadeIn(a);
        $('.content_4').fadeOut();
        $('.button_3').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
        $('.button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('.button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
});
</script>
```

I want to refresh the page on clicking the buttons and show the hidden div. I tried many things but the result was page reload and show the first div again whatever button chosen.

Code above is working well . I want to add extra property to the code. I want page reloads when clicking buttons and keep the div shown.

Example: When click on button "2" I want page to be reloaded and show "//Content of second page goes here"

Edit: Thanks alot @Jan-Drewniak but your idea only solved half of the problem. When I type http:// mysite.com#button_3 as url, page loads the first div not the third. I wish I could make this url work for the third because I want to use this Javascript with the button

```
<script>
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.href = "#button_3";
    window.location.reload();
} 
</script>
```

as I think this may satisfy my needs.

Comment: can you explain why you need page reload ? as your code is working fine as per your requirement, please give explanation for further requirement.

Comment: I want page reload so that all ads on page reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content_1">
    //Content of first page goes here
</div>
<div id="content_2" style="display:none;">
    //Content of second page goes here
</div>
<div id="content_3" style="display:none;">
    //Third page content goes here
</div>

<p id ="container" style="font-weight:bold;" >Pages: 
    <a href="#button_1" id="button_1"> 1</a>
    <a href="#button_2" id="button_2"> 2</a>
    <a href="#button_3" id="button_3"> 3</a>
</p>
<div class="clearLeft"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#container').click(function(){
            location.reload();
        });
        var hashes = window.location.href.split('#');
        var index = hashes[1].split('_')[1];
        var a = 200;
        if(index == 1){
            $('#content_1').fadeIn(a);
            $('#content_2').fadeOut();
            $('#content_3').fadeOut();
            $('#content_4').fadeOut();
            $('#button_1').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
            $('#button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        }else if(index == 2){
            $('#content_1').fadeOut();
            $('#content_2').fadeIn(a);
            $('#content_3').fadeOut();
            $('#content_4').fadeOut();
            $('#button_2').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
            $('#button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        }else if(index == 3){
            $('#content_1').fadeOut();
            $('#content_2').fadeOut();
            $('#content_3').fadeIn(a);
            $('#content_4').fadeOut();
            $('#button_3').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
            $('#button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        }else if (index == 4) {
            $('#content_1').fadeOut();
            $('#content_2').fadeOut();
            $('#content_3').fadeOut(a);
            $('#content_4').fadeIn();
            $('#button_4').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
            $('#button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
            $('#button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        };
    });
</script>

<style>
    .pages
    {
        position:relative;
        top:20px;
        font:1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#000033;
        font-weight:bold;
        width:200px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    .pages ul
    {
        marging:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    .pages li
    {
        list-style-type:none;
        float:left;
        margin-left:5px;
    }

    .pages li a
    {
        padding:5px 7px 7px 5px;
        border:1px solid #999999;
        background-color:#99FF99;
        text-decoration:none;  
        display:block;
    }

    .pages li a:hover
    {
        background-color: #00CCFF;    
    }

    .clearLeft
    {
        clear:left;
    }

    .clearRight
    {
        clear:right;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation, because other users could be find this answer useful too

Answer (score 0):

You just missed to include the jquery.js required. It works.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know that my code is working. But I need some help adding a new value to the code ... Kindly read the question again and with its edited part

Answer (score 0):

Generally, It looks like your trying to make tabbed content. The javascript approach would be to use `location.hash` to select which content to show on the page, so a url ending with `#content_1` would display the div with an id of `content_1`.

This can be done with CSS though, using the `:target` selector.

Here is a pretty good tutorial on how to achieve the desired effect, and it achieves the goal of showing the correct content when the user reloads the page.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/a-simple-image-gallery-using-only-css-and-the-target-selector/

If you want to stick with the javascript approach though, you can change the buttons to this:

```
<p>Pages: 
<a href="#button_1" id="button_1"> 1</a>
<a href="#button_2" id="button_2"> 2</a>
<a href="#button_3" id="button_3"> 3</a></p>
```

and then use this in your javascript

```
var urlHash = window.location.hash
$(urlHash).trigger('click')
```

and change the `.button_1` `.button_2` `.button_3` to `#button_1` `#button_2` `#button_3`in the rest of the jquery selectors.

**EDIT**

alright, in case I wasn't clear with the above suggestion, here's how to implement the `window.location.hash` behaviour in your code. It's important that this gets called after the click functions have already been defined.

This should solve your problem:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="content_1">    
//Content of first page goes
</div>
<div id="content_2" style="display:none;">
//Content of second page goes here
</div>
<div id="content_3" style="display:none;">
//Third page content goes here
</div>

<p>Pages: 
<a href="#button_1" id="button_1"> 1</a>
<a href="#button_2" id="button_2"> 2</a>
<a href="#button_3" id="button_3"> 3</a></p>
<div class="clearLeft"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var a = 200;

$('#button_1').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
$('#button_1').click(function(){
    $('#content_1').fadeIn(a);
    $('#content_2').fadeOut();
    $('#content_3').fadeOut();
        $('#content_4').fadeOut();
    $('#button_1').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
    $('#button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('#button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('#button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
$('#button_2').click(function(){
    $('#content_1').fadeOut();
    $('#content_2').fadeIn(a);
    $('#content_3').fadeOut();
        $('#content_4').fadeOut();
    $('#button_2').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
    $('#button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('#button_3').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('#button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});
$('#button_3').click(function(){
    $('#content_1').fadeOut();
    $('#content_2').fadeOut();
    $('#content_3').fadeIn(a);
        $('#content_4').fadeOut();
        $('#button_3').css("background-color","#00CCFF");
        $('#button_1').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('#button_2').css("background-color","#99FF99");
        $('#button_4').css("background-color","#99FF99");
});

var urlHash = window.location.hash
$(urlHash).trigger('click')

});
</script>
```

p.s. I changed the content classes to ids, so you'll need to update your css accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot but there is some problems.. Please see the edited part of the question @Jan-Drewniak

Answer (score 0):

[See the Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/28pjK/1/)

Pls include this link in the head section of your html page.

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```